# Handbrake-CLI on Synology NAS

Tags: bash, shell, nas, synology, handbrake

I installed Docker on my Synology NAS (DS415+) and tried to run the handbrake-cli (via [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/supercoder/docker-handbrake-cli/) package) over ssh.
However, something seems to be broken. I get the following error message after a simple `sudo docker run -d supercoder/docker-handbrake-cli -i ~/_inProgress/input/movie.mkv -o ~/_inProgress/output/test.mp4` (I shortened the error message for readability):

```
- hb_init: starting libhb thread
- HandBrake 0.10.1 (2015030800) - Linux x86_64 - https://handbrake.fr
- 4 CPUs detected
- Opening /var/services/homes/xxx/_inProgress/input/movie.mkv...
- CPU: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  C2538  @ 2.40GHz
- Intel microarchitecture Silvermont
- logical processor count: 4
- OpenCL: library not available
- hb_scan: path=/var/services/homes/xxx/_inProgress/input/movie.mkv, title_index=1
- libbluray/bdnav/index_parse.c:162: indx_parse(): error opening /var/services/homes/xxx/_inProgress/input/movie.mkv/BDMV/index.bdmv
- libbluray/bdnav/index_parse.c:162: indx_parse(): error opening /var/services/homes/xxx/_inProgress/input/movie.mkv/BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
- libbluray/bluray.c:2182: nav_get_title_list(/var/services/homes/xxx/_inProgress/input/movie.mkv) failed
- bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead
- libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 5.0.1
- libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.
- libdvdread: Can't stat /var/services/homes/xxx/_inProgress/input/movie.mkv
- No such file or directory
- libdvdread: Could not open /var/services/homes/xxx/_inProgress/input/movie.mkv
- libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
- dvd: not a dvd - trying as a stream/file instead
- hb_stream_open: open /var/services/homes/xxx/_inProgress/input/movie.mkv failed
- scan: unrecognized file type
- libhb: scan thread found 0 valid title(s)
- No title found.
- HandBrake has exited.
```

I followed [this blog post](https://www.ivonet.nl/post/757) originally and got the same message there.

Executing the same thing on my desktop works without any problems.
Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this section yet. I posted it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the docker instance, your input and output file do not exist in the container. You need first to mount the input and output directories of you file system as volumes (as shown in the blog post you shared)

```
-v ~/_inProgress/output/:/outout:rw
-v ~/_inProgress/input/:/input:ro
```

And then you use those paths in the options:

```
-i /input/<file>
-o /output/<file>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Well, looked like I just had a typo and forgot `sudo`. However, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have added [code](http://ivo2u.nl/5u) to github supporting the [blogpost](http://ivo2u.nl/5n) mentioned above. Hope it will explain things.